# cannot find database after connecting to mysql in linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, tomcat, jdbc

Linux-Ubuntu 
    Problem : Cannot find mysql database after connection is made to mysql

```
1. I have a war file deployed in webapps folder at /srv/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/
War name is InIndia.war

2. I have deployed inindiadb.properties in classpath which is /srv/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/lib

Contents of inindiadb.properties

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inindia
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=admin

3. I have mysql installed and running

netstat -vulntp |grep -i mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      563/mysqld

4. MySql Database has inindia database and inindia has 3 tables (place , user_roles , users)

mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+

| Database           |

+--------------------+

| information_schema |

| inindia            |

| mysql              |

| performance_schema |

| test               |

+--------------------+

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use inindia;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;

+-------------------+

| Tables_in_inindia |

+-------------------+

| place             |

| user_roles        |

| users             |

+-------------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


5. The problem is when I restart my tomcat , a connection is made to the mysql but in tomcat logs it says that 

**catalina.out**

SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 18, 2014 11:02:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/InIndia] startup failed due to previous errors


**localhostlocalhost.2014-04-18.log**

INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 18, 2014 10:50:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.inindia.listener.ApplicationInfoLoaderListener
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM PLACE order by placeName]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'inindia.PLACE' doesn't exist
```

- I am not able to figure out the error. The error says that inindia.Place cannot be found but the database as well as table is present.
- It connects to the URL mentioned in inindiadb.properties file
- I even wrote a java class to connect to the mysql server and displayed as output data of one of the tables. Connection and Data fetching both were successful.
- Even I deployed the same on my local tomcat in windows which is deployed properly.Hence the war doest seem to have a problem

I am new to linux.Please let me know if there any setting to be made in mysql server.like giving previlage to database or something similar

Comment: Your table name is all lowercase, and you're querying in all uppercase. Depending on environment settings (and settings controlled in `my.cnf`, your identifier names could be case sensitive)

Comment: Hi , Thanks Colin. Its now working fine. Case thing worked. Converted my table to uppercase. Will make sure next time all my table name and the name used in code are same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table name is case sensitive. Use proper case for it